# why does map() display my items in a column vs a row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create react movie app for my hw and I'm following a tutorial.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc9_Bqzy2YQ) I'm trying to make the movie display in a row so that I can scroll through them.

```
return (
    <div className='container movie-app'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <MovieList movies={movies} />
        </div>
          
      </div>
        
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function MovieList(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        {props.movies.map((movie,index) => (<div>
            <img src={movie.Poster}  alt="movie"></img>
        </div>) )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm getting an error code of

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:79 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

I tried to fix the key error by assigning it key={imdbID} in movielist.js but that did nothing. I tried changing the classes of the divs to see if that would help but that also did nothing.

Comment: A `<div>` is a block element; they display top-to-bottom if you don't use some CSS rules to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this :

```
function MovieList(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        {props.movies.map((movie,index) => (<div key={index}>
            <img src={movie.Poster}  alt="movie"></img>
        </div>) )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

You just need to add `key={index}` or whatever you want, like `id` if you have a `move.id`

---

For the display in column, it's because `div` is a `display: block` by default, if you want to be a row you need to style your `div` with `display: inline-block`
or you can also style the parent with `flex` etc...

Comment: And if you ask why `key` is needed :

"Unique keys are important for performance improvements. When we insert, delete, or update the list, React re-renders the array elements. In this case, React uses the key to identify each item. Therefore, React only re-renders where modification is needed and, no re-rendering happens to existing items."  
from : [link](https://www.datainfinities.com/18/each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop#:~:text=Unique%20keys%20are%20important%20for,rendering%20happens%20to%20existing%20items)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, for the row, the problem is with your `CSS`. You can style the `div` inside the `map` function using `CSS` and assign `inline-block` value to the `display` property, there are other solutions as well.

---

For the `key` issue, maybe you added it to the `img` element, not the `div` (inside the `map`) and each `key` should be unique.

---

This should fix your problems:

```
function MovieList(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        {props.movies.map((movie, index) => (<div key={index} style={{display: "inline-block"}}>
            <img src={movie.Poster}  alt="movie"></img>
        </div>) )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And please make sure that you didn't add any global `div` styles that can override `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it would fix the problem,

```js
function MovieList(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        {props.movies.map((movie,index) => (<div>
            <img src={movie.Poster} key={index} alt="movie"></img>
        </div>) )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why would this fix the problem?